# Nginx is active but restarting php7.2-fpm nginx still fails

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04

Was installing Wordpress along with the LEMP stack following a youtube tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4beEybPzYqQ.

No errors per step except when running `systemctl restart php7.2-fpm nginx` returns error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So, I did `systemctl status nginx.service`, which returns

```
 ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-09 16:30:12 EET; 34min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 18582 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
  Process: 18584 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18583 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 18585 (nginx)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─18585 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
```

And `journalctl -xe`:

```
-- 
-- Unit anacron.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
jaan  09 17:04:45 zae anacron[21177]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-01-09
jaan  09 17:04:45 zae anacron[21177]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
jaan  09 17:09:01 zae CRON[21298]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for us
jaan  09 17:09:01 zae CRON[21299]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean 
jaan  09 17:09:01 zae systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun starting up.
jaan  09 17:09:01 zae CRON[21298]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for us
jaan  09 17:09:01 zae systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
```

Everything looks fine to me? 
I checked syslog but at the time of running  `systemctl status php7.2-fpm.service` it doesn't show anything.

/var/log/nginx/error.log is completely empty for some reason too.

Where should I start looking for the cause of this?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. I simply removed all mysql-server, php, nginx related files including dependencies, rebooted... and somehow it works perfectly now.